# Best approach to deal with subclasses in a List with separate dependencies

Tags: java, oop

In doing some restructuring on a project of mine, I've been attempting to better utilise object oriented concepts in my code but I'm not sure how to structure this particular situation:

A method can trigger one of three possible "events", with each event having a dependency on a particular type (Player, Block, World) which needs to happen at runtime as they are deserialised from a file. In an attempt to simplify the execution path I structured it like this so they can all be part of a List which just executes a single method:

```
public interface IEvent {
    void trigger();
}

public class PlayerEvent implements IEvent {

   private Player player;

   public void passPlayer(Player player){
       this.player = player;
   }

   public void trigger(){
       // player does things
   }

}

 public class BlockEvent implements IEvent {

   private Block block;

   public void passBlock(Block block){
       this.block = block;
   }

   public void trigger(){
       // block does things
   }

}
```

However, since each event is dependent on a Player or Block depending on its type, I would have to iterate over the list and downcast each object using instanceof to pass the relevant dependency.

```
 public void executeEvents(){
     for(IEvent event : events){
         if(event instanceof PlayerEvent){
            ((PlayerEvent) event).passPlayer(player);
         } else {
            ((BlockEvent) event).passBlock(block);
         }
         event.trigger();
     }
 }
```

I read that downcasting should never be done under any circumstances, so I've been wondering what alternatives I could use that would follow a similar simple execution path but falls under good OOP practice? Or should I just eliminate the interface altogether and have a separate List for each event type?

Answer (score 0):

> I read that downcasting should never be done under any circumstances,
>   so I've been wondering what alternatives

I would not generalize.  Applications/libraries that generate code or use reflection generally may use downcast.
In other cases, downcast should indeed be avoided.

You have multiple ways to achieve your goals without downcasting.

1) Don't  manipulate a too broad type in the List.   Additionally you could make `IEvent` a generic interface and generalize `passPlayer()` and `passBlock()` in `pass()` that you will move up in the interface.
The interface could look like :

```
public interface IEvent<T> {
    void trigger();
    void pass(T t);
}
```

And implementation of it could look like :

```
public class PlayerEvent implements IEvent<Player> {

    private Player player;

    public void trigger() {
        // player does things
    }

    @Override
    public void pass(Player t) {
    }

}
```

Now with a more specific typed List you could write :

```
private Player player = ...;

public void executeEvents() {
    List<IEvent<Player>> events = ...;
    for (IEvent<Player> event : events) {
        event.pass(player);
    }
}
```

2) Use the visitor pattern to benefit from a double dispatch.

> Event -> Visitor -> processing.

Each `pass()` method become a method of the Visitor.
You could enrich the `IEvent` interface to add an `accept()` method that accepts a `Visitor` :

```
public interface IEvent {
    void trigger();
    void accept(Visitor visitor);
}
```

Here the Visitor interface and implementation :

**Visitor interface**

```
public interface Visitor {

    void visitBlockEvent(BlockEvent block);

    void visitPlayerEvent(PlayerEvent player);

}
```

**Visitor implementation**

```
public class ProcessEventVisitor implements Visitor {

    private Player player;
    private Block block;

    @Override
    public void visitBlockEvent(BlockEvent blockEvent) {
        // do your processing
    }

    @Override
    public void visitPlayerEvent(PlayerEvent playerEvent) {
        // do your processing       
    }

}
```

`IEvent` subclasses delegate now to the Visitor parameter the processing :

```
public class PlayerEvent implements IEvent{

    public void trigger() {
        // player does things
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.visitPlayerEvent(this);
    }

}
```

And the client code can now look like :

```
private Player player;

public void executeEvents() {
    List<IEvent> events = ...;
    ProcessEventVisitor visitor = new ProcessEventVisitor();
    for (IEvent event : events) {
        event.accept(visitor);          
    }
}
```